# Jersey filter registration via web xml not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, web.xml

I have a filter which should validate Ids of incoming requests if the resource it is send to is annotated with IdValidation.
I tried to add this filter in the web xml as described in [this](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) tutorial. However the filter is not invoked when testing a method with the IdValidation annotation.

```
@Provider
@IdValidation
public class IdValidationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        this.requestContext = requestContext;
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
        if (map.containsKey("someId")) {
            // Do some validation and abort if nessecary
        }
    }
}
```

The interface I use to add this filter.

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IdValidation {}
```

The web xml. I tried without the provider classnames at first because I think this is not necessary since the filter is in the same package, but this didn't work either.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.IdValidationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Provider
public class IdValidationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {


        for (Annotation annotation : resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaredAnnotations()) {

            if (IdValidation.class == annotation.annotationType()) {
                 this.requestContext = requestContext;
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
            if (map.containsKey("someId")) {
                    // Do some validation and abort if nessecary
            }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a parameter, I suggest you should have a look at Jersey's [Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) support.